# updating cram_pl

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What has been changed??

I was using my roslisp and cram langguage perfectly, and when I decide to update the
ros-electric- (..) package, because ubuntu said me there are somes update, the cram language breaks!!

when you do:

; SLIME 2011-10-0
CL-USER> (ros-load:load-system "cram_language" :cram-language)

hapend:
Lock on package SB-THREAD violated when defining BARRIER as a
structure while in package TCR.SYNCHRONIZATION-TOOLS.
[Condition of type SYMBOL-PACKAGE-LOCKED-ERROR]
See also:
SBCL Manual, Package Locks [:node]

Restarts:
0: [CONTINUE] Ignore the package lock.
1: [IGNORE-ALL] Ignore all package locks in the context of this operation.
2: [UNLOCK-PACKAGE] Unlock the package.
3: [TRY-RECOMPILING] Recompile synchronization-tools and try loading it again
4: [RETRY] Retry loading FASL for #<SYNCHRONIZED-TOOLS-SOURCE-FILE "synchronization-tools" "synchronization-tools">.
5: [ACCEPT] Continue, treating loading FASL for #<SYNCHRONIZED-TOOLS-SOURCE-FILE "synchronization-tools" "synchronization-tools"> as having been successful.
--more--

and when you do anything, hapend:

WARNING:
System `cram-language' is compiled by a different process. Waiting for compilation of blocking file to finish.

and remains so for ever!!!

What is de solution??

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11536/updating-cram_pl/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cram_pl hasn't been released for quite a while. What happened was that that sbcl (part of roslisp_support) was updated to version 1.0.50 which caused the released version of cram_pl to fail.

I just did another release of cram_pl and as soon as it propagates through the debian build process, the fixed version should be available. In the meantime you can install it from source. The current development version should work.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on 2011-10-16**:
thank you! I have downloaded your release, and now I can compile the libraries.